# Repeating a macro on VBA, Looping

Tags: sql, vba, integration

My problem today is related to looping over several elements in the same macro.
The macro simply takes data from a DB with SQL query directly written on an Excel sheet. It works perfectly but I have difficult to figure out the way to add one (or 2) other query. I don't really care about how the output will be displayed on my excel sheet but I would like to understand how to add the other query to the first macro. You can imagine that i want to combine 2 times the same macro as you can see below. The only difference between the first ant the second macro would be the database information on the top (SERVER, DB, USER, PASS), the name of the const (Const pcSHEET_SQL As String = "SQL"),  the name of the const (Const pcSHEET_Balance_log As String = "Balance_log"), the name of the sub (Sub TRADER())

My objective is to have 1 button instead of 3 for each macro on my excel sheet and to have 1 sheet for the 3 SQL query when I have one sheet per query currently. 
Thank you for your help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TRADER()

Const pcSERVER  As String = "***"
Const pcDB      As String = "***"
Const pcUSER    As String = "***"
Const pcPASS    As String = "***"

Const pcSHEET_SQL As String = "SQL"
Const pcSHEET_Balance_log As String = "Balance_log"

Dim adoCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim sSql As String
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long


'---start---

On Error GoTo errHandler

Sheets(pcSHEET_Balance_log).Columns("A:C").Clear

'SQL作成
With Sheets(pcSHEET_SQL)
    sSql = ""
    j = 1
    Do While .Range("A" & j) <> ""
        sSql = sSql & .Range("A" & j) & " "
        j = j + 1
    Loop
End With


'SQL実行

adoCon.CommandTimeout = 200

adoCon.Open "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};" & _
            "Server=" & pcSERVER & ";" & _
            "Port=5432;" & _
            "Database=" & pcDB & ";" & _
            "Uid=" & pcUSER & ";" & _
            "Pwd=" & pcPASS & ";" & _
            "sslmode=prefer;" 'require;"

adoRs.Open sSql, adoCon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

'取得ﾃﾞｰﾀ無し
    If adoRs.BOF And adoRs.EOF Then
        MsgBox "No matching records found."
        GoTo exitHandler
    End If

'adoRs：フィールド出力
For i = 1 To adoRs.Fields.Count
    Cells(1, i) = adoRs.Fields(i - 1).Name
Next i

'adoRs：データ出力
adoRs.MoveFirst
Sheets(pcSHEET_Balance_log).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset adoRs

'書式設定
With Sheets(pcSHEET_Balance_log).Range(Range("A1"), Cells(1, 
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count))

With .Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

With .Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

End With

exitHandler:
    If Not adoRs Is Nothing Then
        Set adoRs = Nothing
    End If
    If Not adoCon Is Nothing Then
        Set adoCon = Nothing
    End If

    Exit Sub

 errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")"
GoTo exitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: a constant is a constant not variable so if these change you would need a separate query for each variation, otherwise have them as local variables and set their values in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

**RECOMMENDATION**

I suggest you to create a more standard and reusbale Sub that only do the query with `Server, DB, User, password, sheetSQL, SheetBalance` passed by value.

**My Version**

```
Sub SUB_NAME(ByVal Server As String, ByVal DB As String, ByVal User As String, ByVal Password as String)
    const pcSheet_Foo as String ="" 'what do you want'
    const pcSheet_Bar as String="" 'what do you want'
    'Your Things Here'
End Sub
```

**ADVICES**

*Advice #1*

You can also pass `ByVal` a single string `SQLString` with all Server, DB, User, ecc... and than work on the string inside the Sub to extract the information, just to minimize the sub's parameters.

**E.G.**

```
Sub SQL_WhatIsGoingToDo(ByVal SQL As String, ByVal PC_Sheet_foo As String, ByVal PC_Sheet_bar as String)
    'Work on the string here'
    'Your query here'
End Sub
```

*Advice #2*

SE recognizes the apostrophe as a multilne comment, remember to add another apostrophe at the end of the line while posting for a better reading of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If i understood you want me to separate the database information and input and output sheet names on different Sub and to call the rest of the macro in each sub ? Still I have the const name cannot be the same in the macro since I have different SQL in different Sheet on my excel.

Comment: @delalma Yes it's always better to use reutilizable and clean code.
Instead of make some cons you can easily declare them as Dim and than pass them ByVal

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry it is still difficult to figure out how to rewrite this properly.           Sub TRADER(ByVal SERVER As String, ByVal DB As String, ByVal USER As String, ByVal PASS As String)

Const SERVER  As String = "***"
Const DB      As String = "***"
Const USER    As String = "***"
Const PASS    As String = "***"

Dim pcSHEET_SQL As String
Dim pcSHEET_Balance_log As String

Call GEN

End Sub


Sub GEN()